# Extracting .rar files in Windows with current datetime

Tags: windows, zip, rar

One thing I like about Windows zip files is that the extracted files automatically have the current time (as opposed to the original time).  I have yet to find a way to apply the same for extracted rar files using 7zip.  Is there a way to do it using any program?

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" behaviour is to preserve the date and time of the original file.  This could be classed as a bug with winzip rather than a missing feature of 7z.

I don't think you'll be able to convince 7z to update the times at extraction, but you can use a [third party utility](http://www.petges.lu/) to mass update them for you.